# MySQL Sorting By Three Columns in DESC Order

Tags: mysql, sorting, field

I am relatively new to MySQL and I am having difficultly trying to sort a table by three columns.

It is a database that has stored data for thousands of videos and I would like to create a tab on my website that lists recommended videos to the user.

If possible, it would be optimal to only sort the last 100 most recently added videos (records) which have been auto incremented by the 'key' column.

Out of the 100 ordered records, I will only actually retrieve five records from the database and store them into PHP variables.

I am trying to get it to sort the columns as follows.

```
key DESC
rating_score DESC
view_count DESC
```

I previously used another MySQL statement that sorts videos by two columns that works.

```
SELECT  `title`, `duration`, `rating_score`, `imageurl`, `player_url` FROM (SELECT * FROM `archived_videos` ORDER BY `key` DESC LIMIT 0,210) AS ttbl ORDER BY `rating_score` DESC
```

My current and modified version of the above MySQL statement that sorts by three columns is written as follows.

```
SELECT  `title`, `duration`, `rating_score`, `imageurl`, `player_url` FROM ((SELECT * FROM `archived_videos` ORDER BY `key` DESC LIMIT 0,100) AS ttbl (SELECT * FROM `archived_videos` ORDER BY `view_count` DESC) AS ttbl) ORDER BY `rating_score` DESC LIMIT 0,5
```

If someone who is fluent in MySQL could take a look at this you would be a life saver.

Comment: This comment is mostly for people thinking about answering.  The question seems to be a bit misleading.  The desired result is (I think) the 5 highest rated entries out of the 100 latest.  Just sorting by the `key` column would not get the desired result.

Answer (score 3):

You can actually sort on multiple columns in a single [`SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) statement, there's no need to use sub-queries:

```
SELECT
    title, duration, rating_score, imageurl, player_url
FROM
    archived_videos
ORDER BY
    key DESC,
    rating_score DESC,
    view_count DESC
LIMIT 5
```

The results/columns will be sorted in the order you list them. First, they'll sort by the `key` column, then these will be sorted upon the `rating_score`, then the `view_count` - each keeping the order set by the column prior.

**UPDATE** (top-5 of latest 100)
I mis-read the original question the first time around; If the desire is to select to top 5 videos out of the latest 100, you can use a single sub-query to get the latest 100 and then an outer query to get the top 5:

```
SELECT
    title, duration, rating_score, imageurl, player_url
FROM (
    SELECT
        title, duration, rating_score, imageurl, player_url
    FROM
        archived_videos
    ORDER BY
        key DESC
    LIMIT 100
    ) AS top_100
ORDER BY
    rating_score DESC,
    view_count DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: See my comment on the original question

Comment: Thank you for putting in the time and effort to help me out I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT  `title`, `duration`, `rating_score`, `imageurl`, `player_url` 
FROM (
    SELECT * 
    FROM `archived_videos` 
    ORDER BY `key` DESC 
    LIMIT 100
) AS sub 
ORDER BY `rating_score` DESC, `view_count` DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: @user1769348 Glad it helped!  If this answers your question, [please mark it as the accepted answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).